# html Heading levels and when to use them

Tags: html

I apologize for the ignorance but, I am having a hard time figuring out when to change my headings between H1-H6. I am trying to teach myself code on codeacemy.com and my understanding is to change your heading for every title for example:

```
<h1>Introduction</h1>
  <p>This is the intro</p>

<h2>Body</h2>
  <p>This is the body</p>

<h3>Conclusion</h3>
  <p>This is the conclusion</p>
```

Code academy would like me to use the same heading multiple times(as shown below) is this right or wrong? At what point do I start using different headings? please help me clarify so that I can be more productive and informed in my mission to write code.

Code Academy ex:

```
  <h2>Ethiopia</h2>
    <p>Ethiopian beans can be divided into 3 categories: Longberry, Shortberry, and Mocha. Longberry varieties consist of the largest beans and are often considered of the highest quality in both value and flavor. Shortberry varieties are smaller. The Mocha variety is a highly prized commodity. Mocha Harars are known for their peaberry beans that often have complex chocolate, spice and citrus notes.</p>
  <a href="#">Learn More about Ethiopia</a>
</li>
<li>
  <h2>Costa Rica</h2>
  <p>Costa Rican coffee beans are considered among the best in the world. Tarrazu is thought to produce the most desirable coffee beans in Costa Rica. In 2012, Tarrazu Geisha coffee became the most expensive coffee sold by Starbucks in 48 of their stores in the United States, using the Clover automated French press. The finest coffee is typically grown at altitudes of 1200 to 1700 meters.</p>
  <a href="#">Learn More about Costa Rica</a>
</li>
<li>
  <h2>Kenya</h2>
  <p>The acidic soil in highlands of central Kenya, just the right amount of sunlight and rainfall provide excellent conditions for growing coffee plants. Coffee from Kenya is of the 'Colombia mild' type, and is well known for its intense flavor, full body, and pleasant aroma with notes of cocoa and high grade coffee from Kenya is one of the most sought-after coffees in the world.</p>
```

Comment: Just think about a book, essay or any other writing. The chapters would have a h1 on top, then sub-chapters a h2. If you sub-divide those sub-chapters, the sub-sub-chapters would have a h3... in other words, hierarchical.

Comment: Take a look here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp

Comment: To avoid confusion, these are "heading" elements and not "headers" which are an entirely different element.

Answer (score 5):

h1 is usually used for the main header of the page.This indicates that this text is more important than other texts. h2 or h3 can be used for the sub-headers which indicates less important text. This follows on till h6.

In your example all the countries are in h2 tag which shows they are equally important in the semantics of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Headers are used to divide sections, just as if you were writing a report. For example https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#headings-and-sections.

You should repeat levels (h1's, for example) where your document represents the same "level" -- chapters, for example.

Headers are doubly important with assistive technologies (i.e., screen readers) which allow sight-impaired people to "see" the structure of you page. Sections marked with H1 would be considered the top-level set of divisions, H2 would be sub-sections of their related H1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Codeacademy is perfectly right. You can reuse the same header-element multiple times. You can style them seperatly using CSS.

Another thing is SEO (Search-engine-optimization). Google likes it, when you keep order in your header-tags. Don't do large jumps from H1 to H6 and back to H2. Just handle it like this: H1 is the heading for the whole page. H2 can be used as headings for articles. H3s are subtitles inside these articles. I often only use H1-H3.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this: the `<h1>` title is the root title, i.e. the main title of the page. There is almost always only one of these. `<h2>` subtitles are direct children of the `<h1>` title. There could be many. Similarly, `<h3>` subtitles are children of the `<h2>` title that comes before it. And `<h4>` is a child of `<h3`> and so on. Or to put it in code:

```
<h1>The main title</h1>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
<p>A paragraph of text goes here...</p>
<h3>Sub-subtitle</h3>
<p>The nitty gritty of this section.</p>
<h2>Another Subtitle</h2>
<p>Some more text...</p>
<h2>Conclusion</h2>
<p>The final paragraph.</p>
```

Which gives us a hierarchy of headings like this:

- `<h1>`

  - `<h2>`

    - `<h3>`
  - `<h2>`
  - `<h2>`

That HTML above doesn't make the intended document structure at all obvious. It would be better to more clearly show our intent. I'll use HTML5 `<section>` elements to do this:

```
<h1>The main title</h1>
<section>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    <p>A paragraph of text goes here...</p>
    <section>
        <h3>Sub-subtitle</h3>
        <p>The nitty gritty of this topic.</p>
    </section>
</section>
<section>
    <h2>Another Subtitle</h2>
    <p>Some more text...</p>
</section>
<section>
    <h2>Conclusion</h2>
    <p>The final paragraph.</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

The difference between headline-tags is basically all about the looks.

You can organize your writing within your browser by utilizing different headline-tags.